# change color of items one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops

I wrote a script that creates a set of smaller circles arranged in a circle, which are added to the DOM one by one with a loop. After first loop is done (so I would expected this to be when `i == 54`) I would like to start another loop, starting from the first circle in a list and one by one changing the color of the circles from grey to red.

This is my code:

```js
var i = 1;
var appendCircle = function loop() {

  setTimeout(function() {
    var $circle = "<div class='circle circle" + i + "' style='transform:rotate(" + 7.2 * i + "deg) translate(3em)'></div>";
    var $container = $(".circles-wrapper .circles");
    $container.append($circle);
    i++;

    if (i < 55) {
      loop();
    }
  }, 20);

  // this is the problem because this change color of all small circles at once.

  if (i == 54) {
    setTimeout(function() {

      $(".circle").each(function() {
        $(this).css({
          "background": "blue"
        });
      })
    }, 20);
  }
};

setTimeout(appendCircle, 100);
```

```css
.circles-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 39%;
  left: 51%;
}
.circles {
  position: relative;
  transform: rotateY(48deg);
}
.circle {
  width: .2em;
  height: .2em;
  margin: -.2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ceced0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circles-wrapper">
  <div class="circles"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're giving each circle the class "circle"+index so all you have to do is loop through each index and change the background color of each element.  What I did was used the same loop function and after i reached 55 I took the mod 55 of it and used that to select the circle.  Code and snippet below.

I also noticed that some circles overlap.  if you generate 50 circles then there won't be any overlap.  I wrote the code below to reflect this.

```js
var i = 1;
var appendCircle = function loop() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (i < 51) {
  var $circle = "<div class='circle circle" + i + "' style='transform:rotate(" + 7.2 * i + "deg) translate(3em)'></div>";
  var $container = $(".circles-wrapper .circles");
  $container.append($circle);
    }
 else{
  var circleIndex = (i % 51)+1;
  $(".circle"+circleIndex).css("background-color", "blue");
 }
 
 if(i<109){
  loop();
 }
 i++;
  }, 20);
};

setTimeout(appendCircle, 100);
```

```css
.circles-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 39%;
  left: 51%;
}
.circles {
  position: relative;
  transform: rotateY(48deg);
}
.circle {
  width: .2em;
  height: .2em;
  margin: -.2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ceced0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circles-wrapper">
  <div class="circles"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer also thanks for fixed overlap issue

Answer (score 0):

After your first pass you probably want to find the circle created and modify those. You are giving them a class of `circle + i` so you can easily find them. Check the code snip. I added a third pass just because.

```js
var i = 1,
  CIRCLE_COUNT = 52;
var appendCircle = function loop() {

  setTimeout(function() {
    i++;

    // first pass
    if (i < CIRCLE_COUNT * 1) {

      var $circle = "<div class='circle circle" + i + "' style='transform:rotate(" + 7.2 * i + "deg) translate(3em)'></div>";
      var $container = $(".circles-wrapper .circles");
      $container.append($circle);
    } 
    // second pass
    else if (i < CIRCLE_COUNT * 2) {
      $(".circle" + (i % CIRCLE_COUNT+1)).css('background', 'blue');
    }
    
    // third pass
    else if (i < CIRCLE_COUNT * 3) {
      $(".circle" + (i % CIRCLE_COUNT+1)).remove();
    }
    
    // keep looping?
    if (i <= CIRCLE_COUNT * 3)
      loop();

  }, 20);


};

setTimeout(appendCircle, 100);
```

```css
.circles-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 39%;
  left: 51%;
}
.circles {
  position: relative;
  transform: rotateY(48deg);
}
.circle {
  width: .2em;
  height: .2em;
  margin: -.2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ceced0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circles-wrapper">
  <div class="circles"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this? i put a timeout function in your `.each()` in order to make a delay between each iteration of the loop when you change the color of the circles to blue

```js
var i = 1;
var appendCircle = function loop() {

  setTimeout(function() {
    var $circle = "<div class='circle circle" + i + "' style='transform:rotate(" + 7.2 * i + "deg) translate(3em)'></div>";
    var $container = $(".circles-wrapper .circles");
    $container.append($circle);
    i++;

    if (i < 55) {
      loop();
    }
  }, 20);

  // this is the problem because this change color of all small circles at once.

  if (i == 54) {
    var time = 50;
    $(".circle").each(function() {
      var $this = $(this)
      setTimeout(function(){
        $this.css({
          "background": "blue"
        }); 
      }, time)
      time += 50;

    });
  }
};

setTimeout(appendCircle, 100);
```

```css
.circles-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 39%;
  left: 51%;
}
.circles {
  position: relative;
  transform: rotateY(48deg);
}
.circle {
  width: .2em;
  height: .2em;
  margin: -.2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ceced0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circles-wrapper">
  <div class="circles"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the CSS of just one element, then start a timeout to change the next one.

```js
var i = 1;
var appendCircle = function loop() {

  setTimeout(function() {
    var $circle = "<div class='circle circle" + i + "' style='transform:rotate(" + 7.2 * i + "deg) translate(3em)'></div>";
    var $container = $(".circles-wrapper .circles");
    $container.append($circle);
    i++;

    if (i < 55) {
      loop();
    }
  }, 20);

  var j = 0;

  function changeColor() {
    $(".circle").eq(j).css("background", "blue");
    j++;
    if (j >= $(".circle").length) {
      clearInterval(changeInterval);
    }
  }
  if (i == 53) {
    setInterval(changeColor, 20);
  }

}
setTimeout(appendCircle, 100);
```

```css
.circles-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 39%;
  left: 51%;
}
.circles {
  position: relative;
  transform: rotateY(48deg);
}
.circle {
  width: .2em;
  height: .2em;
  margin: -.2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ceced0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circles-wrapper">
  <div class="circles"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has features that make animations like this reasonably trivial, though you need to understand several methods.

jQuery's [.delay()](https://api.jquery.com/delay/), [.promise()](https://api.jquery.com/promise/), [.then()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) and javascript's [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) can be exploited as follows :

```
var appendCircles = function($container) {
    //create and append hidden circles
    for(var i=0; i<50; i++) {
        $("<div class='circle'></div>").css('transform', 'rotate(' + 7.2 * i + 'deg) translate(3em)').hide().appendTo($container);
    }

    //find the freshly appended hidden circles
    var $circles = $container.find(".circle");

    //initial delay
    $circles.eq(0).delay(100).promise()
    .then(function() {
        //show the circles, one by one
        return $circles.get().reduce(function(promise, el) {
            return promise.then(function() {
                return $(el).show().delay(20).promise();
            });
        }, $.when());//$when() is a resolved promise that gets the built promise chain started
    })
    .then(function() {
        //make circles blue, one by one
        return $circles.get().reduce(function(promise, el) {
            return promise.then(function() {
                return $(el).css('backgroundColor', 'blue').delay(20).promise();
            });
        }, $.when());//$when() is a resolved promise that gets the built promise chain started
    });
};

appendCircles($(".circles"));
```

**[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epWKgd?editors=001)**

`.reduce()` probably needs some explanation. `$circles.get()` returns an array and `.reduce(...)` is used to build a promise chain equivalent to `initialPromise.then(...).then(...).then(...)`. This trick is performed twice, in sequence, to give the initial "show" effect followed by the color-change effect.

This suite of methods is worth learning if you want to make custom animation sequences with jQuery.